# Truth value of empty set

Tags: python, set, truthiness

I am interested in the truth value of Python sets like `{'a', 'b'}`, or the empty set `set()` (which is not the same as the empty dictionary `{}`). In particular, I would like to know whether `bool(my_set)` is `False` if and only if the set `my_set` is empty.

Ignoring primitive (such as numerals) as well as user-defined types, https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth says:

> The following values are considered false:
>
> - [...]
> - any empty sequence, for example, `''`, `()`, `[]`.
> - any empty mapping, for example, `{}`.
> - [...]
>
> All other values are considered true

According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range, a set is not a sequence (it is unordered, its elements do not have indices, etc.):

> There are three basic sequence types: lists, tuples, and range objects.

And, according to https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict,

> There is currently only one standard mapping type, the *dictionary*.

So, as far as I understand, the set type is not a type that can ever be `False`. However, when I try, `bool(set())` evaluates to `False`.

Questions:

- Is this a documentation problem, or am I getting something wrong?
- Is the empty set the only set whose truth value is `False`?

Comment: same behavior for any iterable ? i.e. with dict.items()

Comment: It almost certainly is a mistaken omission: the `set` built-in type came relatively late to the game (version 2.2 or 2.3). They likely never updated the docs here to add `or an empty set`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga But doesn't the same apply to `dict`s as well? It's been around pretty much since the beginning, but was omitted.

Comment: @ChristianDean I believe `dict` was addressed here: "any empty mapping, for example {}"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh, Ok. I guess your right.

Comment: Question solved, but someone should file a documentation bug http://bugs.python.org/

Comment: @Chris_Rands I created an issue on the Python bug tracker, see https://bugs.python.org/issue30803

Comment: the fix was merged.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

After looking at the source code for CPython, I would guess this is a documentation error, however, it could be implementation dependent and therefore would be a good issue to raise on the Python bug tracker.

Specifically, [object.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a66f9c6bb134561a24374f10e8c35417d356ce14/Objects/object.c#L1313) defines the truth value of an item as follows:

```
int
PyObject_IsTrue(PyObject *v)
{
    Py_ssize_t res;
    if (v == Py_True)
        return 1;
    if (v == Py_False)
        return 0;
    if (v == Py_None)
        return 0;
    else if (v->ob_type->tp_as_number != NULL &&
             v->ob_type->tp_as_number->nb_bool != NULL)
        res = (*v->ob_type->tp_as_number->nb_bool)(v);
    else if (v->ob_type->tp_as_mapping != NULL &&
             v->ob_type->tp_as_mapping->mp_length != NULL)
        res = (*v->ob_type->tp_as_mapping->mp_length)(v);
    else if (v->ob_type->tp_as_sequence != NULL &&
             v->ob_type->tp_as_sequence->sq_length != NULL)
        res = (*v->ob_type->tp_as_sequence->sq_length)(v);
    else
        return 1;
    /* if it is negative, it should be either -1 or -2 */
    return (res > 0) ? 1 : Py_SAFE_DOWNCAST(res, Py_ssize_t, int);
}
```

We can clearly see that the value is value would be always true if it is not a boolean type, None, a sequence, or a mapping type, which would require tp_as_sequence or tp_as_mapping to be set.

Fortunately, looking at [setobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c#L2127) shows that sets do implement tp_as_sequence, suggesting the documentation seems to be incorrect.

```
PyTypeObject PySet_Type = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0)
    "set",                              /* tp_name */
    sizeof(PySetObject),                /* tp_basicsize */
    0,                                  /* tp_itemsize */
    /* methods */
    (destructor)set_dealloc,            /* tp_dealloc */
    0,                                  /* tp_print */
    0,                                  /* tp_getattr */
    0,                                  /* tp_setattr */
    0,                                  /* tp_reserved */
    (reprfunc)set_repr,                 /* tp_repr */
    &set_as_number,                     /* tp_as_number */
    &set_as_sequence,                   /* tp_as_sequence */
    0,                                  /* tp_as_mapping */
    /* ellipsed lines */
};
```

[Dicts](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L3254) also implement tp_as_sequence, so it seems that although it is not a sequence type, it sequence-like, enough to be truthy.

In my opionion, the documentation should clarify this: mapping-like types, or sequence-like types will be truthy dependent on their length.

**Edit** As user2357112 correctly points out, `tp_as_sequence` and `tp_as_mapping` do not mean the type is a sequence or a map. For example, dict implements `tp_as_sequence`, and list implements `tp_as_mapping`.

Comment: Slightly aside -- is the Python language actually defined by the documentation, or by the reference implementation?

Comment: @peterthomassen: There's barely anything that can be considered a spec, really. It's not like C or C++, with a standards body and a mostly-thorough official standard. The docs are often incomplete, and the exact behavior of the interpreter isn't normative for other implementations.

Comment: Note that the presence of `tp_as_sequence` doesn't mean an object is a sequence and the presence of `tp_as_mapping` doesn't mean an object is a mapping. The language has evolved since those members were designed and named.

Comment: Where in the above is the `__nonzero__` (or `__bool__` in python 3) taken into account?

Comment: @shadow: Python-level `__bool__` corresponds to the `v->ob_type->tp_as_number->nb_bool` part, which is the C-level counterpart. Depending on whether the type is written in C or Python, either `__bool__` or `nb_bool` will be a wrapper for the other.

Comment: @shadow, It's actually not considered. Builtin types differ from user-defined types. 
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4e624ca50a665d7e4d527ab98932347ff43a19b0/Objects/typeobject.c#L6083

Comment: @user2357112 Beating me to the punch again.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh I raised this on the Python bug tracker, see https://bugs.python.org/issue30803

Answer (score 28):

The documentation for [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) states that this method is called for truth value testing and if it is not defined then [`__len__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) is evaluated:

> Called to implement truth value testing and the built-in operation bool(); [...] When this method is not defined, `__len__()` is called, if it is defined, and the object is considered true if its result is nonzero. If a class defines neither `__len__()` nor `__bool__()`, all its instances are considered true.

This holds for any Python object. As we can see `set` does not define a method `__bool__`:

```
>>> set.__bool__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'set' has no attribute '__bool__'
```

so the truth testing falls back on `__len__`:

```
>>> set.__len__
<slot wrapper '__len__' of 'set' objects>
```

Therefore only an empty set (zero-length) is considered false.

The part for [truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) in the documentation is not complete with regard to this aspect.

Answer (score 18):

That part of the docs is poorly written, or rather, poorly maintained. The following clause:

> instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a `__bool__()` or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False.

really applies to *all* classes, user-defined or not, including `set`, `dict`, and even the types listed in all the other clauses (all of which define either `__bool__` or `__len__`). (In Python 2, `None` is false despite not having a `__len__` or Python 2's equivalent of `__bool__`, but that exception is [gone since Python 3.3](http://bugs.python.org/issue12647).)

I say poorly maintained because this section has been almost unchanged since at least [Python 1.4](https://docs.python.org/release/1.4/lib/node5.html#SECTION00311000000000000000), and maybe earlier. It's been updated for the addition of `False` and the removal of separate int/long types, but not for type/class unification or the introduction of sets.

Back when the quoted clause was written, user-defined classes and built-in types really did behave differently, and I don't think built-in types actually had `__bool__` or `__len__` at the time.

Comment: Just a heads up that magic methods can be implementation-dependent: in Python 2, `__bool__` does not exist, while `__nonzero__` provides the same functionality, which I discovered the hard way.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh: Yup. The `__nonzero__` name dates back to before Python had a bool type. Back then, it returned either 0 or 1, and the method was thought of as testing nonzeroness instead of coercing to bool.